# MapReduce project with data mining

Tags: hadoop, parallel-processing, mapreduce, data-mining

I am planning to do a **MapReduce project** involving **Hadoop** libraries and testing it on big data uploaded at **AWS**. I have not finalized an idea yet. But I am sure it will involve some kind of data processing, **MapReduce design patterns** and possibly **Graph algorithms, Hive and PigLatin**. I would really appreciate if someone can give me some ideas about it. I have few of mine in mind.

In the end I have to work on some large data set and get some information and derive some conclusions. For this I have used **Weka** before for data mining, (using Trees).

But I am not sure if that is the only thing I can work with right now (using Weka). Is there any other ways by which I can work on large data and derive conclusions on the large data set?

Also how can I involve graphs in this ?

Basically I want to make a research project but I am not sure what exactly I should be working on and what it should be like ? Any thoughts ? suggestive links/ideas ? Knowledge sharing ?

Comment: Such a question is not appropriate for Stack overflow. Plus, it has been asked numerous times before, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953787/using-hadoop-map-reduce-for-programming-language-design-course-project http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894396/hadoop-machine-learning-data-mining-project-idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375102/data-mining-project-ideas?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you check [Apache Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org/), it a scalable machine learning and data mining framework that should integrate nicely with Hadoop.

Hive gives you SQL-like language to query big data, essentially it translates your high-level query into MapReduce jobs and run it on the data cluster.

Another suggestion is to consider doing your data processing algorithm using R, it is a statistical software (similar to matlab), and I would recommend instead of the standard R environment is to use [R Revolution](http://www.revolutionanalytics.com/products/revolution-r.php), which is an environment to develop R, but with much powerful tools for big data and clustering.

**Edit:** If you are a student, R Revolution has a free academic edition.

**Edit:** A third suggestion, is to look at [GridGain](http://www.gridgain.com/) which is another Map/Reduce implementation in Java that is relatively easy to run on a cluster.

Answer (score 0):

As you are already working with MapRedude and Hadoop, you can extract some knowledge from your data using [Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org/) or you can get some ideas from this very good book:

http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds.html

This books provide ideas to mine  Social-Network Graphs, and works with graphs in a couple of other ways too.

Hope it helps!